# how can i find the value of an input from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Im writing this code for a school project, its something like this:

```
valid_entries = ['y', 'n', 'hatchback', 'estate', 'saloon']
model_options = {
    'Hatchback' : 535000,
    'Saloon' : 495000,
    'Estate' : 625000
}
total_price = 0

model_chosen = input("Which car model do you want to buy?\n> ")
while model_chosen not in valid_entries:
    print("Invalid Input\nTry again")
    model_chosen = input("Which car model do you want to buy?\n> ")
```

Is there a way i can access the values and compare that to the input and add it to the score?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ? And can you be more precise ? witch values do you want to compare and what is the store, `model_options` ?

Comment: you need to learn about python dictionaries and how to access the elements in dictionary

Comment: If this is a school project, you might want to consider implementing some input validation. The input asks "Which car model do you want to buy?" - but gives no indication of models available. Also the input requires a case-sensitive match so hatchback will display Invalid Input but Hatchback will work (assuming @Kev Rob's recommendation of discarding valid_entries list)

Comment: oh ok
ill add the ".lower()" function to the input so i can validate.
and ill print the models before the input
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value with this syntax: dict[key]. For example in your code models_options[Estate] has a value of 625000. You don't really need the list valid_entries. You can try the code below:

```
valid_entries = ['y', 'n', 'hatchback', 'estate', 'saloon']
model_options = {
    'Hatchback' : 535000,
    'Saloon' : 495000,
    'Estate' : 625000
}
total_price = 0

model_chosen = input("Which car model do you want to buy?\n> ")
while model_chosen not in model_options:
    print("Invalid Input\nTry again")
    model_chosen = input("Which car model do you want to buy?\n> ")

total_price+=model_options[model_chosen]

print(total_price)
```

Comment: You are welcome. I'm new, could you accept my answer or give me a vote please?

Comment: Sure! Here you go!

Answer (score 0):

The value is model_options[model_chosen], what exactly do you want to do?
can you do:
total += model_options[model_chosen].